# pandas 3 months rolling median

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate a 3 months rolling median. For now I have this:

```py
df['ODPLYW'].rolling(min_periods=90, window=90).median()
```

But I want the window to be exactly 3 months. `rolling` accepts only fixed window. I also tried this:

```py
df['ODPLYW'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="3M")).median()
```

But it gives output only every third month. Any ideas?

df sample:

```
            ppKODH  COROKH  COMSCH  CODZIEN     COPRZP  COMSCK  index    ODPLYW
datetime
1974-11-01      10    1975       1        1  70.400002      11      0  1.304238
1974-11-02      10    1975       1        2  58.500000      11      1  1.083777
1974-11-03      10    1975       1        3  56.900002      11      2  1.054135
1974-11-04      10    1975       1        4  52.099998      11      3  0.965210
1974-11-05      10    1975       1        5  47.500000      11      4  0.879990
1974-11-06      10    1975       1        6  39.500000      11      5  0.731781
1974-11-07      10    1975       1        7  43.000000      11      6  0.796622
1974-11-08      10    1975       1        8  38.799999      11      7  0.718813
1974-11-09      10    1975       1        9  36.000000      11      8  0.666940
1974-11-10      10    1975       1       10  33.000000      11      9  0.611361
1974-11-11      10    1975       1       11  31.200001      11     10  0.578014
1974-11-12      10    1975       1       12  32.400002      11     11  0.600246
1974-11-13      10    1975       1       13  32.400002      11     12  0.600246
1974-11-14      10    1975       1       14  31.200001      11     13  0.578014
1974-11-15      10    1975       1       15  30.000000      11     14  0.555783
1974-11-16      10    1975       1       16  30.600000      11     15  0.566899
1974-11-17      10    1975       1       17  31.200001      11     16  0.578014
1974-11-18      10    1975       1       18  32.400002      11     17  0.600246
1974-11-19      10    1975       1       19  30.600000      11     18  0.566899
1974-11-20      10    1975       1       20  40.200001      11     19  0.744749
1974-11-21      10    1975       1       21  39.500000      11     20  0.731781
1974-11-22      10    1975       1       22  33.000000      11     21  0.611361
1974-11-23      10    1975       1       23  30.000000      11     22  0.555783
1974-11-24      10    1975       1       24  28.200001      11     23  0.522436
1974-11-25      10    1975       1       25  25.200001      11     24  0.466858
1974-11-26      10    1975       1       26  26.400000      11     25  0.489089
1974-11-27      10    1975       1       27  25.799999      11     26  0.477973
1974-11-28      10    1975       1       28  26.400000      11     27  0.489089
1974-11-29      10    1975       1       29  38.799999      11     28  0.718813
1974-11-30      10    1975       1       30  36.700001      11     29  0.679908
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `df.rolling('90d').mean()`

This does not fully solve your situation, but at least it can solve the missing day problem.